# Malicous modification of web page data before Posting to server

Tags: asp.net, security, owasp

I am currently in the process of designing an MVC5 web application for a financial purpose and have a security related question.

The example is a quotation of which the flow is:

1. User requests quotation from Server
2. User is presented with quote for £100
3. User submits the form to accept the quote (sends
   the value presented to the server in a POST).

Is it possible for a malicious user to update data maliciously that is presented to them on the client (change the quote from £100 to £50) before the submit button is pressed to post the data back up to the server?

I know its possible to intercept the POST request and modify that using various tools.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the transport security measures in place, as well as the security of the user's machine. So, basically, without any more information: Yes, that is possible, see [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) for more information that exceeds SO's limits.

**Edit**: As for your question, of course the user can manipulate it's own post request, for example using the developer tools that come with most browsers.

The server should validate the user input for various reasons as good as it can and remember it's original quote. If via whatever way (forged request, MITM, ...) anything is not right, the server should detect that.

Simply believing what the users post is not a good enough effort, security-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jan, however is a MITM attack not after the POST has happened so the data is on its way to the server?

Comment: Yeah. The server should validate the user input for various reasons as good as it can and remember it's original quote. If via whatever way (forged request, MITM, ...) anything is not right, the server should detect that. Simply believing what the users post is not a good enough effort, security-wise.